happybase connection.tables() returning TTransportException.END_OF_FILE in python
I am trying to save data in hbase with python using hapybase. Even if connection to thrift2 seems ok, I am getting this error when trying to get hbase tables list.

... raise TTransportException(type=TTransportException.END_OF_FILE,
thriftpy2.transport.base.TTransportException:
TTransportException(type=4, message='TSocket read 0 bytes')

Here is my code:
...
conn = happybase.Connection(host="127.0.0.1", port=9090)
conn.open()
table = conn.table(topic_name)

rows = table.scan()

if not rows:
    try:
        conn.create_table(topic_name, {'cf': {}})
        print("Table created!")
    except:
        print("Maybe table already exists but just empty!")
else:
    print(row for row in rows)

tables = conn.tables()
print(tables)
...

This is the output.



What is strange is I don't have error about ".create_table()" or ".table()" happybase functions, only about getting tables list : ".tables()". But of course in hbase command line, no table is shown so no table created.
What am I doing wrong ?
